# Display role separately while creating role discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How can i display role members separately from online members, when i creating role?

[Need to enable this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoVnD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [discord.Guild.create_role() documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=hoist#discord.Guild.create_role), you need to set to true parameter "hoist".

> hoist (bool) – Indicates if the role should be shown separately in the member list. Defaults to False